# Multisim issue with current in differential amplifier

Tags: multisim

I did simple differential amplifier simulation:

[image]

As you can see Q2 current is negative, it is not possible right?
Also, if input signals on both transistor base are equal, u1 (volt metter) should show 0V but instead shows some nV, I know it's not much but looks like multisim try to be smarter then it should.

PS: The amplification depends on transistor beta value right? So the output voltage will be B times bigger than input difference. Is that understanding correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emitters are at 2.42V, since Q1 is on. Q2 is off as it’s B-E voltage is negative. 0.444uA is Q2’s reverse bias leakage current, which is tiny.

Multisim rightly reports voltages and currents, regardless of their magnitudes. Would you prefer a simulation package that made its own mind up whether or not a current or voltage should be ignored?